# Adding child features in a many-to-many relation using geospatial overlaps with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I feel like this is obvious so asking primarily if I'm missing something...

In QGIS, I'm trying to make a relationship (many-to-many) between two spatial layers such that the child features of one layer are those which spatially intersect it.

So, for example, say you have rivers and countries. One country could contain many rivers, but one river could flow through many countries.

I want, in the countries layer, to select all the rivers as child features, which spatially intersect with it.

At present I have *countries*, *rivers*, and *countries-rivers* pivot table set up, but all that allows me to do in the N-N form widgets is to *manually* select all the river I want associated with a country (or all the countries I want associated with a river).

I don't want to *manually* select them, I want the GIS to select them by intersection.

In a one-to-many relationship I could have a the foreign key field calculated by an expression so that it contained the *id* of the river, but with many-to-many I can't think of a way to get it to work (obviously a concatenated list of all the river id's isn't going to work)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your countries-rivers table is your junction table which already contains the id of every country and id river combination for your n:m relation? I'm not sure what you want to achieve: Select a country in the canvas and on this slection  select all rivers that intersects? Do want to select by attribute or by location?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do - add child features (as in create a new child feature from a parent layer form)? Bulk edit child features from a parent layer form? Or do you just want to quickly select features from another layer, that intersect with a polygon in your current layer? If it's the last one, you could use Select by Polygon while on your polygon layer, right click on the canvas, and choose a layer to select intersecting features from. Looks a bit like this (from QGIS 3.4 - more options now). https://twitter.com/qgis/status/1040330507194650624

Comment: As I said in the question "I don't want to manually select them, I want the GIS to select them by intersection". So if I were to digitise a new river, it would _automatically_ become a child feature of the country or countries it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone will post an improvement on this, because it's not very neat, but my current solution is to run the following SQL

```
delete from countries_rivers;
insert into countries_rivers (country_id, rivers_id)
SELECT
country_id,
rivers_id
FROM
countries inner join rivers on  st_intersects(st_buffer(countries.geom,-1),rivers.geom)
```

It updates the joining layer with all intersects. The small buffer is to prevent rivers which border countries but belong in only one from showing up in both. The SQL is set as a trigger on both layers. Obviously it requires the layers to be in Spatialite (or presumably Postgis etc).

The downside it that it requires a joining table for all combinations of layers, and two triggers, which is quite complex to manage on a large project with lots of these types of links.